# Objective C selector table functions

Tags: objective-c, macos, reverse-engineering, objc-message-send

I am trying to figure out which method objc_msgSend() will call.

While looking at assembly of any function in Appkit or Cocoa or Any framework based on Objective-C framework, I always get stucked at objc_msgSend().

Does any one has any idea how to reach the actual function call from here?

I remember while browsing I have seen some open source code which was kind of Map for which function will be called based on selector (integer value). I guess it was from Apple (not sure). I am trying to find that link from almost 2 days, but cannot find it. If anyone who that link please share.

In following assembly,    I am trying to solve this call

```
 __text:001C6E46                 call    _objc_msgSend
```

It should be great, if some one can help me understand the complete procedure.

```
__text:001C6DC0 ; -[NSWindow _windowMovedToRect:]
__text:001C6DC0 __NSWindow__windowMovedToRect__ proc near ; DATA XREF: __inst_meth:00993418o
__text:001C6DC0
__text:001C6DC0 var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
__text:001C6DC0 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
__text:001C6DC0 arg_8           = dword ptr  10h
__text:001C6DC0 arg_C           = dword ptr  14h
__text:001C6DC0 arg_10          = dword ptr  18h
__text:001C6DC0 arg_14          = dword ptr  1Ch
__text:001C6DC0
__text:001C6DC0                 push    ebp
__text:001C6DC1                 mov     ebp, esp
__text:001C6DC3                 push    esi
__text:001C6DC4                 push    ebx
__text:001C6DC5                 sub     esp, 30h
__text:001C6DC8                 call    $+5
__text:001C6DCD                 pop     ebx
__text:001C6DCE                 mov     esi, [ebp+arg_0]
__text:001C6DD1                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_C]
__text:001C6DD4                 mov     [esp], eax
__text:001C6DD7                 call    _PSbuttondown
__text:001C6DDC                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_C]
__text:001C6DDF                 test    edx, edx
__text:001C6DE1                 jz      short loc_1C6E1D
__text:001C6DE3                 mov     eax, [esi+80h]
__text:001C6DE9                 or      dword ptr [eax+0B8h], 1000000h
__text:001C6DF3                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
__text:001C6DF6                 mov     edx, [ebp+arg_C]
__text:001C6DF9                 mov     [esp+8], eax
__text:001C6DFD                 mov     [esp+0Ch], edx
__text:001C6E01                 mov     eax, [esi+8]
__text:001C6E04                 mov     edx, [esi+0Ch]
__text:001C6E07                 mov     [esp], eax
__text:001C6E0A                 mov     [esp+4], edx
__text:001C6E0E                 call    _NSEqualPoints
__text:001C6E13                 test    al, al
__text:001C6E15                 jnz     loc_1C6ED6
__text:001C6E1B                 jmp     short loc_1C6E50
__text:001C6E1D ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:001C6E1D
__text:001C6E1D loc_1C6E1D:                             ; CODE XREF: -[NSWindow _windowMovedToRect:]+21j
__text:001C6E1D                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
__text:001C6E20                 mov     [esp+8], eax
__text:001C6E24                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_C]
__text:001C6E27                 mov     [esp+0Ch], eax
__text:001C6E2B                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_10]
__text:001C6E2E                 mov     [esp+10h], eax
__text:001C6E32                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_14]
__text:001C6E35                 mov     [esp+14h], eax
__text:001C6E39                 mov     eax, ds:(off_926DC8 - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6E3F                 mov     [esp+4], eax
__text:001C6E43                 mov     [esp], esi
__text:001C6E46                 call    _objc_msgSend
__text:001C6E4B                 jmp     loc_1C6ED6
__text:001C6E50 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:001C6E50
__text:001C6E50 loc_1C6E50:                             ; CODE XREF: -[NSWindow _windowMovedToRect:]+5Bj
__text:001C6E50                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
__text:001C6E53                 mov     [esp+8], eax
__text:001C6E57                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_C]
__text:001C6E5A                 mov     [esp+0Ch], eax
__text:001C6E5E                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_10]
__text:001C6E61                 mov     [esp+10h], eax
__text:001C6E65                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_14]
__text:001C6E68                 mov     [esp+14h], eax
__text:001C6E6C                 mov     eax, ds:(off_91D198 - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6E72                 mov     [esp+4], eax
__text:001C6E76                 mov     [esp], esi
__text:001C6E79                 call    _objc_msgSend
__text:001C6E7E                 mov     eax, ds:(off_91A4B8 - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6E84                 mov     [esp+4], eax
__text:001C6E88                 mov     eax, ds:(off_928EE8 - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6E8E                 mov     [esp], eax
__text:001C6E91                 call    _objc_msgSend
__text:001C6E96                 mov     [esp+0Ch], esi
__text:001C6E9A                 mov     edx, ds:(_NSWindowDidMoveNotification_ptr - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6EA0                 mov     edx, [edx]
__text:001C6EA2                 mov     [esp+8], edx
__text:001C6EA6                 mov     edx, ds:(off_91B0DC - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6EAC                 mov     [esp+4], edx
__text:001C6EB0                 mov     [esp], eax
__text:001C6EB3                 call    _objc_msgSend
__text:001C6EB8                 mov     eax, ds:(_NSAccessibilityMovedNotification_ptr - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6EBE                 mov     eax, [eax]
__text:001C6EC0                 mov     [esp+8], eax
__text:001C6EC4                 mov     eax, ds:(off_91B030 - 1C6DCDh)[ebx]
__text:001C6ECA                 mov     [esp+4], eax
__text:001C6ECE                 mov     [esp], esi
__text:001C6ED1                 call    _objc_msgSend
__text:001C6ED6
__text:001C6ED6 loc_1C6ED6:                             ; CODE XREF: -[NSWindow _windowMovedToRect:]+55j
__text:001C6ED6                                         ; -[NSWindow _windowMovedToRect:]+8Bj
__text:001C6ED6                 add     esp, 30h
__text:001C6ED9                 pop     ebx
__text:001C6EDA                 pop     esi
__text:001C6EDB                 leave
__text:001C6EDC                 retn
__text:001C6EDC __NSWindow__windowMovedToRect__ endp
```

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-12-02-object-file-inspection-tools.html) mentions a tool called [otx](http://otx.osxninja.com/) that appears to decode the selector for you.

Comment: The example on the site I linked to does show otx resolving the objc_msgSend.  Perhaps if you posted some example assembly with the otool and otx output we could further help.

Comment: sorry I confused my comment between. class-dump and otx. I have updated question with assembly.